# got a parser error when reading a CSV file with pandas

Tags: python-3.x

I can't read the csv file with pandas.read_csv(). But after I save the csv file again, I can read the file. What's wrong with this?
I paste part of the error log below:

> pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader.read()
>
> pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx in
>   pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._read_low_memory()
>
> pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx in
>   pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._read_rows()
>
> pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx in
>   pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._tokenize_rows()
>
> pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx in pandas._libs.parsers.raise_parser_error()
>
> ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 2 fields in line
>   4, saw 4

And here are the first 5 lines of my CSV file.

line 1: DeviceUnderTest;"

line 2: User;"g26857"

line 3: Comment;""

line 4: Instrument;"Rohde&Schwarz   CMW 1201.0002k03/108897 3.7.110"

line 5: Test Executive;"R&S CMWrun 1.9.6.251 (Beta)"

Comment: can  yo upaste the first 5 lines of the csv

Comment: may be the line breaks are causing the errors. what operating system are you using while saving the file before reading it with pandas.

Comment: My operating system is win10.@ViswanathPolaki

Comment: just updated the first 5 lines of the csv.@ChrisDoyle

Comment: using your sample line data i cannot reproduce the error you are getting can you also show the line where you load the pandas data. I have tested as `df = pd.read_csv('test.dat', sep=';')` and it happily loads the data into two columns (assuming that there should have been another `"` at the end of line 1). based on your error pandas is saying it was expecting only two fields but it found 4 which would indiciate that you have more fields on that line than on your header line

Comment: So from your point of view, pandas can only read the CSV files with most fields in the header line. If a line below header line has more fields than the header line, pandas would report this error. By the way, what does field mean in this case, columns or rows?@ChrisDoyle